# How use View.OnClickListener with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an application and considering my level it's not easy! I hope you could help me since I didn't succeed with the many links I found on the internet.

I can't add the `onClick` function of View.OnClickListener, each time the Intent function is not recognized. I tried to implement it in the UserViewHolder and `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` class but it doesn't work.

Here is my current code:

---------- kotlin part ---------

```
    package edu.stanford.rkpandey.emojistatus

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


data class User(
    val displayName: String? = "",
    val emojis: String? = ""
)

class UserViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    // Query the users collection
    private val query = db.collection("users")
    val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(query, User::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this).build()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = Firebase.auth

        val adapter = object: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options) {

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(this@MainActivity).inflate(R.layout.item_pack, parent, false)
                return UserViewHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(
                holder: UserViewHolder,
                position: Int,
                model: User
            ) {
                val tvName: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
                val tvEmojis: TextView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.excerpt)
                tvName.text = model.displayName
                tvEmojis.text = model.emojis
            }

        }
        rvUsers.adapter = adapter
        rvUsers.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.miLogout) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Logout")
            auth.signOut()
            val logoutIntent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            logoutIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            startActivity(logoutIntent)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

}
```

------- xml part -------

=> activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

=> item_pack

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="12sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12sp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPack">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            style="@style/NoteTitleFont"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitle"
            tools:text="Note 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/excerpt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDescribe"
            tools:text="test text va se trouver ici, ça va contenir le début de la description du package." />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This code gives this result :

[image]

I would like that when I click on one of the carviews it can go to the activity_pack_detail.
Do you know how to do Intent to PackDetailActivity?

I get this error no matter what I do =>

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you for your answer.
I've updated my post, hoping it gives you more context.
Don't hesitate to tell me if you want more precision :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you are calling [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)'s class constructor with a wrong argument. The first argument should be a [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) and not a View. The keyword `this` is referring in your code to a View and **not** to a context, hence the error.

To solve this, you have to pass a Context object like this:

```
val i = Intent(view.getContext(), PackDetailActivity::class.java)
```

And your error will go away.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I'll try it when I get home tonight and let you know.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hello :) 
Sorry I start a new job so i didn't have time to try it before tonight. 
Yes I changed a little bit the syntaxe but it work well ! I can go on my ViewDetail and I succeed to screen the title and the description. 
But I have an error when I come back to the previews View. I will try to fix it tomorrow.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked well. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Yes your answer help me a lot, you take me on the way to understand an important concept ! 
If I don’t succees to fix my new error, i don’t hesitate to create a new question. 
Thank you very much